# How is map-reduce used in inverted index search?

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search, hadoop, mapreduce, information-retrieval

It is easy to understand how map-reduce is used to collect text and build a large inverted index. But how can map-reduce be used in inverted index search?

Comment: What are you basing the question on? I mean, how do you know it is used for search? AFAIK, the search is usually single threaded, and is relatively cheap. Though, I might be wrong... :|

Comment: I think the tags "algorithm" and "Information Retrieval" are better, so I retagged. If you think I am wrong - roll back or re-edit.

Comment: The concept of building index via mapreduce may easy to understand. But based on my search, it is really difficult to find some good reference to teach people how to do it. I heard something like Solr supports mapreduce building index, but no document or code show it. I am struggling to implement this, could you offer some references about how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*build a large inverted index*, right. But not for search. MapReduce is batch processing.

I'm pretty sure that you don't want to wait until a MapReduce job runs on 2 mio. items and score them, afterwards another Job has to run and sort the scores descending.

But that is only the case for Hadoop. Maybe if you use MapReduce inside of MongoDB, this might be accurate. But still a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MapReduce is mainly used for batch processing, but not search, which has a higher requirement on the response time.